# What event is this and how can I attach something to it? Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I have managed to catch the event im looking for, using an event watcher in firefox.

It seems to indicate the event is called 'input', but ive never heard of this, can anyone offer any insight as I need to attach a function to the event.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.oninput)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although the message "keyup event or mouseup event detected! coming from this element:" would be more correct.

Comment: oninput will only fire if you put some data into the input, while mouse-or key-events also fire if you did not input data.